# Create Line Break in XML NODE using Java DOM Parser

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd

I'm Creating Dynamic XML Document using Java DOM.Kindly find corresponding code below

```
Element cond = doc.createElement("condition");
Text value = doc.createTextNode("simulation/sim-time-sec  ge  0.25 \r\n\r\n dss");
cond.appendChild(value);
event.appendChild(cond);
```

The above code results

```
<condition>simulation/sim-time-sec ge 0.25 dss</condition>
```

But i want node like below

```
<condition>
 simulation/sim-time-sec ge 0.25
 dss
</condition>
```

Kindly Suggest the solution in Java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The *problem* is with your editor in which you're viewing xml doc. However do not add \r.

Answer (score 5):

Use Transformer's setOutputProperty() to build the xml file with indentation

```
    TransformerFactory transfacObj = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transObj = transfacObj.newTransformer();
    transObj.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```

Correct me if 'm wrong

Comment: Hi Stranger, Can you provide the "TransformerFactory" Implementation Code?

Comment: @OpenSourceDev post some related source code and elaborate to the post so it could helpful for all.

Comment: That did not work for me. Can you share some related code.